# Redirect loop issue in prestashop 1.6

Tags: .htaccess, migration, prestashop, infinite-loop, prestashop-1.6

I have installed Prestashop 1.6 in my local Wamp server and it was working fine. When I moved this shop to the actual online domain, it's showing as "This webpage has a redirect loop" in chrome and "The page isn't redirecting properly" in Firefox.
Seems like some configuration has been missed. I changed values in ps_shop_url and made changes in htaccess but still its the same.

Please help

Comment: Is back-office accessible?

Comment: It too has the same problem

Answer (score 5):

In ps_shop_url table you must set domain=localhost, domain_ssl=localhost & physical_uri=/myProject/

In ps_configuration set PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL & PS_SHOP_DOMAIN to localhost

Also go at BackOffice -> Preferences -> SEO & URLs and click [Save] - this will regenerate your .htaccess file and will add the /myProject/ where needed.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the table "**ps_configuration**" and locate the records 
  ***PS_SHOP_DOMAIN*** and ***PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL***, set the correct values.
- Go to the table "**ps_shop_url**" and set the correct values, take care if you have sub-shops or virtual host, most of the errors come from here. 
  Here is an exemple : 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/J947r.jpg
- In the file config/settings.inc.php edit this =>
  define('_DB_NAME_', '**your_datase_name**');
- Delete the .htaccess at the root of the application folder.
- Regenerate the .htaccess in the back-office by disabling and enabling the simplified URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Oliver's answer is appropriate, but here's if you want to do it programmatically (by example for copying a setup to create a new instance on a same domain):

```
/**
* Update the access file of the new sub-domain. Otherwise the user will 
* constantly be redirected to the setup.
*
* @param $errorMessage String array to return the error message.
* @param $name String name of the subdomain to update.
*
* @return Boolean
*/
private function updateAccessFile(&$errorMessage, $name){

    $success = false;

    $fileContent = file_get_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../' . $name . "/.htaccess");

    if ($fileContent !== false){

        $filcontent = str_replace("setup", $name, $fileContent);

        $success = boolval(file_put_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../' . $name . "/.htaccess", $filcontent));
    }

    if (!$success){

        $errorMessage[] = parent::getErrorMessage("SUBDOMAIN_CREATION_CONF_FILE_ERR", "We are not able to update the prestashop main access file.");    
    }

    return $success;
}


/**
* Update the configuration file with the configuration for the new subdomain 
* in order to access the sub-domain affiliated database.
*
* @param $errorMessage String array to return the error message.
* @param $name String name of the subdomain to update.
*
* @return Boolean
*/
private function updateConfigurationFile(&$errorMessage, $name){

    $counter = 0;

    $reader = fopen(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../' . $name .'/config/settings.inc.php', 'r');
    $writter = fopen(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../' . $name .'/config/temp.txt', 'w');

    while (!feof($reader)) {

      $line = fgets($reader);

      if (strpos(strtoupper($line), '_DB_SERVER_') !== false) {

        $line = "define('_DB_SERVER_', '127.0.0.1');\n";

        $counter++;
      }
      elseif (strpos(strtoupper($line), '_DB_NAME_') !== false) {

        $line = "define('_DB_NAME_', '" . $name . "');\n";

        $counter++;
      }
      elseif (strpos(strtoupper($line), '_COOKIE_KEY_')  !== false and !empty($this->fetchEncryptionKey())) {

        $line = "define('_COOKIE_KEY_', '" . $this->saltKey . "');\n";

        $counter++;
      }


      fputs($writter, $line);
    }

    fclose($reader); 

    fclose($writter);

    if ($counter > 0){

        rename(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../' . $name .'/config/temp.txt', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../' . $name .'/config/settings.inc.php');   

    }
    else{

        unlink(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../' . $name .'/config/temp.txt');
    }

    if ($counter !== 3){

        $errorMessage[] = parent::getErrorMessage("SUBDOMAIN_CREATION_CONF_FILE_ERR", "We are not able to update prestashop configuration file.");  
    }

    return (empty($errorMessage) ? true : false);
}
```

And a stored procedure for the database:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE setupStore(IN shopName VARCHAR(50), IN domain VARCHAR(50), IN encryptionKey CHAR(56), OUT success BOOLEAN)

BEGIN
    DECLARE fail BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET fail = true;

    START TRANSACTION;

    SET success = false;

    SET @shop = shopName;

    SET @domain = domain;

    SET @uri = CONCAT('/', shopName, '/');


    SET @query = 'UPDATE ps_shop s INNER JOIN ps_shop_url su ON s.id_shop = su.id_shop SET s.name=?, su.domain=?, su.domain_ssl=?, su.physical_uri=? WHERE s.id_shop=1';

    PREPARE statement FROM @query;

    EXECUTE statement USING @shop, @domain, @domain, @uri;



    SET @query = CONCAT('UPDATE ps_configuration SET value= ? where name=', QUOTE('PS_SHOP_DOMAIN'), 'OR name=', QUOTE('PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL'));

    PREPARE statement FROM @query;

    EXECUTE statement USING @domain;


    SET @query = CONCAT('UPDATE ps_configuration SET value= ? where name=', QUOTE('PS_SHOP_NAME'));

    PREPARE statement FROM @query;

    EXECUTE statement USING @shop;


    DELETE FROM pc_import_config;

    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO pc_import_config(cookie_key) VALUES(?)';

    SET @key = encryptionKey;

    PREPARE statement FROM @query;

    EXECUTE statement USING @key;


    IF fail THEN

        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE

        COMMIT;

        SET success = true;
    END IF;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Note**: *pc_import_config* is not a real prestashop table, I use that table to keep in memory the encryption_key used during data import from the *DataImporter* (abstract class for data import from different data sources into different setups) to use it in the *subDomainManager* (abstract class for creating instance of subdomains from different base setup and then managing them).

Jonathan Parent-Lévesque from Montreal

Answer (score 0):

First Check the table _shop_url and set followings,

- **domain**       = localhost
- **domain_ssl**   = localhost
- **physical_uri** = /yourfoldername/

and don't forget to use the .htaccess file.

If you don't have a .htaccess file for your local deployment, please click below link. Don't forget the replace the string **yourproject** with your folder name.

[.htaccess file for localhost deployment](https://gist.github.com/pranid/9b0cc544ac10ce60bf95e170b8d32aef)